# Github Hosted Runners - CPU performance?

Tags: github-actions

How performant are the CPUs listed on the documentation for github hosted runners (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#supported-runners-and-hardware-resources)?

> Hardware specification for Windows and Linux virtual machines:
>
> 2-core CPU (x86_64)
> ...
>
> Hardware specification for macOS virtual machines:
>
> 3-core CPU (x86_64)
>
> ...

I read this: https://www.datacenters.com/news/what-is-a-vcpu-and-how-do-you-calculate-vcpu-to-cpu to get an idea, but I need some knowledge of the hardware.

Any ideas where to find this information? Preferably from Github

Comment: I'm interested in this as well, I wish they would provide better hardware specification details. I also noticed GitHub has radar for Q1 2023 to improve the macOS runner performance:
https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/506